# How to Set a calculated timestamp as a default value MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create a table that sets an expiry date within 2 weeks of having been created. The next select statement gives me that record:

```
 (SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(WEEK,2,(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)));
```

**| 2014-04-21 18:08:52 |**

But DEFAULT on create table does not allow me to put any expression:

```
create table test (somename varchar(32), expiry TIMESTAMP DEFAULT (SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(WEEK,2,(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))));
```

How can achieve this?
--UPDATE - 
I TRY this trigger but my syntax is wrong:

> CREATE TRIGGER expiryset AFTER INSERT ON test BEGIN DECLARE exp
>   TIMESTAMP; SET @exp := (SELECT
>   TIMESTAMPADD(WEEK,2,(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)));  UPDATE test SET expiry  =
>   @exp WHERE somename = ; END;

**this works but i need to get somename value/column of the insert before the trigger....how can i get this?**

Comment: [ON INSERT trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)?

Comment: I was thinking I could do this with a trigger but even here I do not have much experience. How does this look like? why I get syntax error: CREATE TRIGGER expiryset AFTER INSERT ON test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 UPDATE test SET expiry  = (SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(WEEK,2,(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)));
END;

Comment: Post as an update in your OP with the exact error, please. :)

Comment: Set the value when you create the record in the `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a default value that is neither NULL, nor the current time.